# While Loop - constant variables NOT working with user input boundaries

Tags: python, user-interface, easygui

So the `VALUE_MAX` variable is = to 25, and `VALUE_MIN` is = to 1.
When I type `26`, or `0`, it is supposed to pop up and give the user another chance to input a value within 1-25 range (in easygui window). I have written this code, but I am not sure what is wrong with it. I would very much appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Here is my FULL code for this program: https://github.com/UnknownBob123/Card-Catalogue

Here is my original code for this part:

```
def validate_value(value, item): 

    """Input validation: Checks that the user has input a valid value. 
    """ 

    # If the user presses the Cancel button, function is called to  
    # confirm that the user wants to exit. 
    if value == None: 
        value = query_cancel() 

    # If the user presses the OK button without entering a value, 
    # the no_value() function is called to display an error message 
    # and get input. 
    while value == "": 
      value = no_value(item) 

    # The while loop checks that input is valid (from VALUE_MIN to  
    # VALUE_MAX), and if not an error message is displayed, and the  
    # user is prompted to re-enter the value. 
    while float(value) < VALUE_MIN or float(value) > VALUE_MAX: 
      msg = "Please enter a valid value for " + item + " (from " + str(VALUE_MIN) + " to " + str(VALUE_MAX) + ")." 
      title = "ERROR" 
      value = easygui.enterbox(msg, title) 

        # If the user pressed OK without entering a value, the function 
        # is called to display and error message and get input. 

      while value == "": 
        value = no_value(item) 

        # If the user presses the Cancel button, function is called to  
        # confirm that the user wants to exit. 
      if value == None: 
        value = query_cancel()
        return (value)
```

Comment: So what is the program currently doing when you run it and try to input 0 or 26?

Comment: It just continues as if nothing happened (prompts do you want to add another card? Yes/No), without giving the option to input a value within the 1-25 range. It is probably something simple I've missed out on and can't quite get my head around.

Comment: It also outputs the 0 and 26 when outputting the nested dictionary.

Comment: Try printing all your variables before the `while` loop. `print(float(value), VALUE_MIN, VALUE_MAX)`

Comment: Hmm, okay -- thank you I will try that and definitely will let you know.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried `print(float(value), VALUE_MIN, VALUE_MAX)`, before and after the while loop it did not seem to work, unless I did it incorrectly, would you want me to provide the program?

Comment: Are you sure the validation function is being called?

Comment: I have actually been thinking about whether that is the case, it perhaps isn't being called, everything in the code **seems** fine so this is a bit aggravating for me, as I don't know why it's not being called.

Comment: @Barmar My full program is here: https://github.com/UnknownBob123/Card-Catalogue

Comment: There's nothing that ever calls `validate_value()` in the full script.

Comment: I guess you should call it from `get_fields()`, to validate the values that were entered for the fields.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, thank you @Barmar.